# Serialized values or separate table, which is more efficient?

Tags: database-design, sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails model `email_condition_string` with a `word` column in it. Now I have another model called `request_creation_email_config` with the following columns

1. admin_filter_group:references
2. vendor_service:references
3. email_condition_string:references

`email_condition_string` has many `request_creation_email_config` and  `request_creation_email_config` belongs to `email_condition_string`.

Instead of this model a colleague of mine is suggesting that storing the word inside the same model as comma separated values is more efficient than storing it as a separate model. Is that all right?

Comment: Is request_creation_email_config a model, or just a string?  What is your colleague hoping to save? Disk space? Table joins?

Comment: `email_condition_string` and `request_creation_email_config` are models. I have a `word` column in `email_condition_string`. I am using this pattern. My colleague suggesting that I should store word in the `request_creation_email_config` model as comma separated `word` column instead of having a seperate model called `email_condition_string` to save fetch time. Is he right?

Comment: He's right only if the database is very large.  Otherwise it will all be cached and the fetch time will be insignificant.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how you plan to use this later.

You are anyway one migration (and some code changes ofc) from changing this solution from one to the other. So I would choose whatever, and later benchmark it in a way your users really use the system.

Even better - profile the app and look for bottlenecks first, instead of [optimizing it prematurely](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

If you use PostgreSQL or Oracle one more option is to use array type instead of serialized string. It could be it's more efficient with indexing such type. Or you may want to use full text search solution later.

To summarize - it depends on how you utilize this data and how big the data set is.